# Make WPF DataGrid column editable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I need to make my DataGrid column editable, but can't figure out how to make this.
When I try to edit column I catch an exception "EditItem is not allowed for this view".

My XAML:

```
    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="6,6,5,18" Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}" CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_editCells">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And .cs:

```
public partial class MyView : Window
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get { return myDictionary ; } set { myDictionary  = value; } }

    public MyView()
    {
        // Here is some code that fills dictionary

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

What is the problem? How can I make my second column editable?

Comment: why not use a observablecollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind to a dictionary it enumerates the contents as `KeyValuePair` instances, which is a struct. You cannot edit the members of a struct keeping the same instance (and the properties are get-only in this case).

Bind to a list of class instances instead.

Comment: actually, you can change a member of a struct but it's not recommended

Comment: @wiero: When you access a struct you get a copy of it, so if you edit that struct you will not have changed the instance you probably "meant" to edit. You would need to reassign that instance to where it was taken from, which bindings won't do.

Comment: Thank's. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid works with collections and Dictioanry is a collection of [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx). If you look at this struct you'll see you that it's not mutable.